# Merge Queries using query of queries

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to merge two queries using lucee but there is a bug in lucee that does not do any distinct

it just returns the union all even for union

trying it like this

```
select * from tbl1
union 
select * from tbl2
```

ending up as:

```
Apple
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

is there anything in java i can use directly to make the union work, there is a bug but its in backlog and that will not sure will take how much time to fix

Comment: Which version of lucee are you on?

Comment: Why can't you do this in your database query?

Comment: i answered my own question

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `group by`

```
GROUP BY columnName
```

```
<cfquery name="test" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM a
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM b
    GROUP BY fruitName
</cfquery>
```

UPDATE from comments

```
<cfquery name="test" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM a
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM b
    GROUP BY fruitName
</cfquery>
```

[**DEMO**](https://trycf.com/gist/aec27322db9d5da713faa3499f8c9cca/lucee5?theme=monokai)

[DEMO Union Distinct](https://trycf.com/gist/96656a95d7e4fa67abd1dac23a27b33a/lucee5?theme=monokai)

Comment: I am latest , I tried the groupby clause but i get another error

Comment: in your demo too, i see the apple appear two times

Comment: use UNION DISTINCT will fix it

Comment: Refer to https://trycf.com/gist/3c0deada9b8bd3f93e67b75af27bf5da/lucee5?theme=monokai.  Both the `group by` and `union distinct` methods yield the desired result.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, I'll update `UNION DISTINCT` to my answer. I can remove it if you want to add as a new answer.